# How to calculate a multiplication operator representation?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory, adjoint-operators

> Let $H =\ \mathcal{l}^{2}(\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{C})$ and $A = R + L$,
>   where $L$ is the left-shift operator (and $R$ is the right-shift
>   $(Ra)_{n}=a_{n-1}$). Set
>
> $$U : \mathcal{l}^{2}(\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{C}) \longrightarrow
>  L^{2}([0,1]) ,\quad U(a_n)\ =\ \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}a_n\mathrm
>  e^{2\pi \mathrm int}\text{.}$$ Then $ULU^{-1}$ is multiplication by
>   $\mathrm e^{-2\pi \mathrm it}$ and $URU^{-1}$ is multiplication by
>   $e^{2\pi \mathrm it}$. Therefore $UAU^{-1}$ is multiplication by
>   $2\cos(2\pi t).\\$ Show that $A$ can be represented as a
>   multiplication operator by $t$ on $L^{2}(\mathbb{R},\mathrm d\mu_{1})\oplus
>  L^{2}(\mathbb{R},\mathrm d\mu_2)$, where $\mu_1$, $\mu_2$ have support in
>   $[-2,2]$.

I started to proof, that $UAU^{-1}$ is multiplication by $2\cos(2\pi t)$:
\begin{align}
UAU^{-1} &= U(L+R)U^{-1}\\
&=U(LU^{-1}+RU^{-1})\\
&=ULU^{-1}+URU^{-1}\\
&=( .\ )\ \cdot\ \mathrm e^{-2\pi \mathrm it}\ +\ (\ .\ )\ \cdot\ \mathrm e^{2\pi \mathrm it}\\
&=(\ .\ )\ \cdot\ 2\cos(2\pi t)
\end{align}

Comment: Off-topic, but: Are you from Potsdam?

Comment: ya right... from potsdam